# Como guardar letras em uma variável e exibi-las todas no final formando uma frase/palavra

Tags: c, c++, string

Estou prendendo programação e estou fazendo um código em que eu devo transformar um código em binário em uma frase. Estou transformando o valor binário em decimal, e pegando o valor decimal e comparando a tabela ASCII. Porém não sei como faço para ir guardando as letras que aparecem em uma variável ou vetor para exibi-las todas juntas no final.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int dec=0,num,d=1;
    char charr[25];

    cout<<" Digite o numero binario de 8 dígitos (dígite 0 para parar): ";
    cin>>num;

    do {
    dec = dec+(num%10)*d;
    d = d*2;
    num = num/10;
    }

    while(num!=0);

    charr[0] = 'A', charr[16] = 'Q';
    charr[1] = 'B', charr[17] = 'R';
    charr[2] = 'C', charr[18] = 'S';
    charr[3] = 'D', charr[19] = 'T';
    charr[4] = 'E', charr[20] = 'U';
    charr[5] = 'F', charr[21] = 'V';
    charr[6] = 'G', charr[22] = 'W';
    charr[7] = 'H', charr[23] = 'X';
    charr[8] = 'I', charr[24] = 'Y';
    charr[9] = 'J', charr[25] = 'Z';
    charr[10] = 'K';
    charr[11] = 'L';
    charr[12] = 'M';
    charr[13] = 'N';
    charr[14] = 'O';
    charr[15] = 'P';

    if (dec == 65 or dec == 97)
    {
        cout<<charr[0];
    }

    if (dec == 66 or dec == 98)
    {
        cout<<charr[1];
    }

        if (dec == 67 or dec == 99)
    {
        cout<<charr[2];
    }

        if (dec == 68 or dec == 100)
    {
        cout<<charr[3];
    }

        if (dec == 69 or dec == 101)
    {
        cout<<charr[4];
    }

        if (dec == 70 or dec == 102)
    {
        cout<<charr[5];
    }

        if (dec == 71 or dec == 103)
    {
        cout<<charr[6];
    }

        if (dec == 72 or dec == 104)
    {
        cout<<charr[7];
    }


        if (dec == 73 or dec == 105)
    {
        cout<<charr[8];
    }

        if (dec == 74 or dec == 106)
    {
        cout<<charr[9];
    }

        if (dec == 75 or dec == 107)
    {
        cout<<charr[10];
    }

        if (dec == 76 or dec == 108)
    {
        cout<<charr[11];
    }

        if (dec == 77 or dec == 109)
    {
        cout<<charr[12];
    }

        if (dec == 78 or dec == 110)
    {
        cout<<charr[13];
    }

        if (dec == 79 or dec == 111)
    {
        cout<<charr[14];
    }

        if (dec == 80 or dec == 112)
    {
        cout<<charr[15];
    }

        if (dec == 81 or dec == 113)
    {
        cout<<charr[16];
    }

        if (dec == 82 or dec == 114)
    {
        cout<<charr[17];
    }

        if (dec == 83 or dec == 115)
    {
        cout<<charr[18];
    }

        if (dec == 84 or dec == 116)
    {
        cout<<charr[19];
    }

        if (dec == 85 or dec == 117)
    {
        cout<<charr[20];
    }

        if (dec == 86 or dec == 118)
    {
        cout<<charr[21];
    }

        if (dec == 87 or dec == 119)
    {
        cout<<charr[22];
    }

        if (dec == 88 or dec == 120)
    {
        cout<<charr[23];
    }

        if (dec == 89 or dec == 121)
    {
        cout<<charr[24];
    }

        if (dec == 90 or dec == 122)
    {
        cout<<charr[25];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: dê uma lida na biblioteca de vetores do c++ (vector) ou então crie uma variável string (biblioteca string) e utilize ela concatenando os valores obtidos. Para saber mais sobre string: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ E para vector: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Li seu código, não entendi totalmente o objetivo e qual a dificuldade específica.

Comment: Não não sei como guardar essa conversão ex: 
01010000 é igual a 80 que é igual a 'P' na tabela ascii e 01110010 é igual a 114 que é igual a 'R'. Como eu junto esse 'P' e 'R' e faço eles serem exibidos lado a lado no fim do programa?

Comment: Ainda eu não entendi o que deseja, o que é uma pena porque a pergunta parece interessante. Antes de aprender programar precisa aprender entender o problema e comunicá-lo claramente, aí a programação fica mais fácil. Programação é detalhe, faltam detalhes. Isso parece um amontoado de informações. Talvez eu tenha entendido alguma coisa, mas aí seu código não faz nem perto do que está dizendo.

Comment: Pera ai vamos por partes kk Tenho que pegar uma série de códigos binários e converte-los para a tabela ASCII, ou seja, tem uma mensagem em código binário que eu tenho que converte-la para caracteres e formar a frase.

Comment: Não tem nada de série no código e não há explicação de como pretende fazer isso, muito menos um código que trate isso.

Comment: É um exercício, Fazer um programa que traduza qualquer mensagem em binário! Este código acima é o que estou tentando. Estou aprendendo programar em C/C++, desculpa se ta muito fora do que deve ser feito kk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira coisa é decidir se vai fazer em C ou C++. Parece que vai de C++, então use tudo do C++ e evite as coisas do C.

Tentei fazer aqui de um jeito melhor o que eu entendi que é a questão. Algumas coisas podem ser feitas melhores (pode formatar a saída um pouco melhor, pode trocar o `do-while` por um `for`, pedir uma entrada de texto e não um inteiro, otimizar a performance), mas acho que já é uma grande evolução.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string texto = "";
    while (true) {
        int num;
        cout << "Digite o numero binario de 8 dígitos (dígite 0 para parar): ";
        cin >> num;
        cout << endl;
        if (num == 0) break;
        int dec = 0, d = 1;
        do {
            dec += num % 10 * d;
            d *= 2;
            num /= 10;
        } while (num != 0);
        if (!((dec >= 65 && dec <= 90) || (dec >= 97 && dec <= 122))) {
            cout << "Valor digitado está fora da faixa permitida" << endl;
            continue; 
        }
        texto += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"[(dec &  ~32) - 65];
    }
    cout << texto;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6WBcgV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vsxqssuk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PseudoCrypt.c).

Tirei as coisas desnecessárias e passei usar [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) no lugar de um *array* de `char` que é coisa de C.

Dei uma organizada, inclusive deixei as declarações das variáveis mais perto do seu uso.

Criei um laço que é o mais importante para pedir vários números em sequência. A saída dele é quando digitar um número 0.

Criei a variável `texto` que vai acumulando as letras.

Note que usei extensivamente operadores compostos de atribuição de dados, então `d *= 2` é o mesmo que `d = d * 2`. Isso vale para as demais variáveis, inclusive `texto` que concatena as letras.

Verifiquei se o número digitado está em uma faixa válida da tabela ASCII que se pode fazer a conversão.

Matei todos os `if`s usando matemática. Normalizei o número para o índice da letra. Como o que foi digitado poderia ser maiúsculo ou minúsculo usei os operadores de `&` (`AND`) e `~` (`XOR`) em cima de 32, assim garantimos que o número seja reduzido para a faixa de 65 à 96 (ainda que isso não esteja garantido no código). Também retirei 65 para chegar no 0 do índice. O primeiro `dec` possível equivale à letra `A` ou `a`. O é o índice inicial de um *array* ou `string` (que nada mais é que um *array* de `char`). Com essa operação o resultado será sempre de 0 à 25, exatamente o que desejava (desde que seja digitado um binário equivalente aos caracteres válidos).

Criei um texto com todas as letras posicionadas entre 0 até 25 e com o operador `[]` peguei o índice calculado no índice conforme fórmula acima. A letra encontrada é acumulada em `texto`.

Se não entendeu algum conceito pode fazer novas perguntas específicas para cada dificuldade que encontrar, assim fica mais organizado.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que o exercício pedia. Vou estudar seu código. Eu estou aprendendo c/c++ agora na faculdade. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Só não entendi esta parte: 
 
} while (num != 0);
        dec -= dec > 96 ? 97 : 65;
        texto += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"[dec];

Se puder me explicar, agradeço!

Comment: @CalicoJack dei uma melhorada no código.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, me ajudou muito eu não estava conseguindo fazer esse exercício!

Comment: @CalicoJack dá uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar a resposta (é aí do lado perto das setas de voto, um sinal de *check*) e mais tarde, quando tiver reputação, pode votar em tudo que achar útil no site.